# C++11 ambiguity between single qualified name and two consecutive?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following C++11 program ill-formed?

```
struct a
{
    struct b {  };

    void f() {};
};

extern struct a b;

struct a ::b;

int main()
{
    b.f();
}
```

Why / why not?

The thing of interest here is this line:

```
struct a ::b;
```

Is this a forward declaration of the inner class `a::b`?

Or is this a definition of the global variable `b`?  Equivalent to:

```
struct a (::b);
```

Comment: Are you missing punctuation on extern struct a b; ?

Comment: What is `struct a ::b;` supposed to be?

Comment: Voted down: Type it into a file and try to compile it.   The compiler will answer "Yes, this is ill formed"

Comment: @DaleWilson These types of questions are common here in C++. Just because a compiler accepts it doesn't make it actually valid. So I'm voting it up.

Comment: @DaleWilson: The behaviour of one particular compiler cannot be used to determine if a C++11 program is ill-formed.  The compiler could support the program as an extension, or the compiler could have a bug.

Comment: Reads like a copy/pasted homework question to me.

Comment: @FredLarson That'd be a one hell of a homework :/

Comment: There is no such thing as a *forward declaration of a nested type* (in the sense you are using it, inside `a` you can forward declare the nested type `b`, but you cannot forward declare `a::b` outside of `a`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Standard ref for that?  It seems to satisfy 7p3, "shall redeclare a name introduced by a previous declaration"?

Comment: @user1131467 Is http://pastebin.com/NpQVcgJH perhaps a better example for your real question? Does that avoid the other reasons why this code is invalid?

Comment: Ok Never mind that it doesn't compile.  When the compiler issues an error message on the line "extern struct a b;" you can either assume you have a defective compiler, or you can check your syntax and discover it's wrong before asking the question.  Thanks for the edit though that indicates you are worried about the forward declaration.

Comment: @DaleWilson: I don't know what you mean sorry.  `extern struct a b;` is well-formed.  It declares, but does not define, a variable with the name `b` of type `a`.  The `struct a` type specifier is called an elaborated type specifier.  It means the same as `extern a b;`.

Answer (score 1):

`struct a ::b;` doesn't declare a variable named `b` of type `a`, if that's what you are asking. It's a (redundant) forward declaration of the nested type `a::b`. Whitespace is not generally significant in a C++ program. So your program declares, but never defines, a variable named `b`. That's a violation of One Definition Rule: the program is therefore ill-formed, and the linker will tell you as much.

Comment: Where is this ambiguity between the forward declaration of the inner class `a::b` and the declaration of a variable `::b` of type `a` addressed in the standard?

Comment: `struct a::b;` is a forward declaration, but it itself is ill-formed, since you cannot forward declare the inner type outside the definition of the outer type.

Comment: @Praetorian:  Why isn't it interpreted as `struct a (::b);`?

Comment: This is not correct - `struct a::b;` is basically the same as `int;`.

Comment: @user1131467 GCC [interprets it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=db9fb18b554b3dba2d90c1949971de2c-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419) the way I said (notice the warnings). But I noticed the extern declaration only just  now - you're right that it could be interpreted as the definition of it.

Comment: Scratch that last sentence of mine, it's [illegal](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e83362960731802ba2e3aa4d8948ef82-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419).

Comment: @jrok: Why is your linked example ill-formed?  Which passage in the standard forbids it?  8.3 seems to indicate it should be okay.

Comment: 8.3p1 ...A declarator-id shall not be qualified except for [certain cases that don't apply here]...

Comment: @user1131467 What IgorTandetnik said, I was just gonna paste that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik:  I disagree that the cases don't apply.  Specifically it "refers to the previously declared member of the global namespace", that member being `b`, that was previously declared with `extern struct a b;`.  How do you reason that it doesn't apply?

Comment: That phase you put in quotes is not present in my copy of C++11. Which normative document are you quoting from? Here is the passage in full: A declarator-id shall not be qualified except for the definition of a member function (9.3) or static data member (9.4) outside of its class, the definition or explicit instantiation of a function or variable member of a namespace outside of its namespace, or the definition of an explicit specialization outside of its namespace, or the declaration of a friend function that is a member of another class or namespace (11.3).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I'm using N3485 which is from Nov 12.  If you are using the older official standard then this must be a new change added since C++11 ratification, and explains the confusion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Indeed that is the case.  8.3p1 changed between 2011 and 2012.

Comment: @user1131467: The first thing is to determine whether it parses as `struct (a::b)` or `struct a (::b)`. If I understand it correctly, the parsing is the first, that is `a::b` is considered as a single *nested-name-specifier* and does not refer to the `::b` object of type `struct ::a`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That is correct.  I think it is an unaddressed ambiguity (and hence defect) in the standard.  `struct a::b` could be interpreted as either `struct (a::b)` or `struct a (::b)`.  This didn't come up before because it looks like 8.3p1 changed in 2012 to be more relaxed.  I'll report to isocpp

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11 , C++11 was published in September 2011. How can a document from 2012 be a draft of that? If you want to discuss drafts of C++14, then there's N3690 from May 2013, where 8.3 is different still.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yes, N3485 is from Nov 12.  I still tag it as C++11 and call it such as the changes are usually not so pronounced to be relevant.  This time is a rare exception.

Comment: Also the "forward" declaration is ill-formed, as you cannot have a qualified forward declaration.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos based on the following statement at the *about page* regarding the c++11 tag: [the publicly available draft closest to C++11 is N3337](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B11/info), you shouldn't tag questions regarding drafts newer than n3337 as c++11, I suggest you use c++1y for such cases

Comment: @brunocodutra: Up to and including N3485 is still considered C++11, N3690 and following are considered C++1y.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos could you please point me to a reference for that, I always get confused with all those drafts

Comment: @brunocodutra: It relates to what the policy is regarding changes for a particular draft.  From C++11 official to N3485 inclusive were mainly just bug fixes excepted.  N3690 opened up for major new additions in preparation for C++14.  For a list of papers see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/

Answer (score -3):

**Take 2**

`struct a ::b;` is a well-formed declaration of `struct a::b`.

It is not a *forward* declaration because `struct a::b` has already been
defined. The Standard does not formally define *forward declaration* but it 
is universally accepted to mean a declaration of something that precedes and 
is separate from its definition.

Nor is it a declaration of the global variable `b`.

The whitespace is insignificant, so in order for the putative declaration to
have the suggested ambiguity,

```
/*A*/ struct a::b;
```

would of course have to have the same ambiguity. Rewritten like that, we might 
well agree that it is perfectly obvious what the declaration should mean; but we'd
like to know whether that obvious meaning is vindicated by the Standard.

I will confine my consideration to the C++11 Standard. (I think a resolution
of the question from the C++03 Standard is actually more straightforward).

The Standard distinguishes the *unary scope operator* `::` from the *scope
resolution operator* `::`.

§ 3.4.3 **Qualified name lookup**, para 1:

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the :: scope resolution
>   operator (5.1) applied to a nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration.

§ 3.4.3 **Qualified name lookup**, para 4:

> A name prefixed by the unary scope operator :: (5.1) is looked up in global scope, in the translation unit
>   where it is used.

These citations are not offered to *explain* the distinction, just to show that
it exists. But they deliver right away the point that in `/*A*/`
the operator would have to be the *unary scope operator* for § 3.4.3/4 to
sustain the global-`::b` interpretation of `/*A*/`.

It might well again be obvious that the scope operator in `/*A*/` is *not*
the unary one. But we are referred to § 5.1 **Primary expressions** for
the grammatical definitions of the *unary scope operator* and *scope
resolution operator*, and in any case we have yet to see what is said about the
lookup of `b` when if is the right-hand operand of the *scope
resolution operator*.

At § 5.1.1/8 we find that the operator `::` is defined as the
infix operator of § 3.4.3/1 and also as the unary operator of 
§ 3.4.3/4 in the grammar of  *qualified-id*:

```
qualified-id:
    nested-name-specifier template[opt] unqualified-id
   :: identifier
   :: operator-function-id
   :: literal-operator-id
   :: template-id
nested-name-specifier:
    ::[opt] type-name ::
    ::[opt] namespace-name ::
    decltype-specifier ::
    nested-name-specifier identifier ::
    nested-name-specifier template[opt] simple-template-id ::
```

It is the infix operator when it is the final token of a 
*nested-name-specifier* followed, optionally by `template`, and
then an *unqualified-id* and otherwise it is the unary operator in
the contexts:

```
:: identifier
:: operator-function-id
:: literal-operator-id
:: template-id
```

According to this grammar, the `::` operator must left-associate with a 
*nested-name-specifier* (forming the scope resolution operator) if
it can. According to the grammar, `a::` in `/*A*/` is a *nested-name-specifier*
and `a::b` is a *qualified-id* of the first form 
*nested-name-specifier template[opt] unqualified-id*.

So we are assured that § 3.4.3 **Qualified name lookup** applies to `b` in
`/*A*/` and can refer to § 3.4.3.1 **Class members**, para 1,
for the conclusion that `b` in that context is to be looked up in `a`, not globally:

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name specified after the nested-name-
>   specifier is looked up in the scope of the class (10.2), except for the cases listed below.

None of "the cases listed below" applies to `/*A*/`, and if there is any doubt that
the nested class `a::b` counts as a *member* of `a`, § 9.2 **Class members**, 
para 1, removes it:

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and
>   enumerators.

Having found that `a::b` unamiguously requires `b` to be looked up in `a`,
the question of the well-formed-ness of `/*A*/` becomes the question of whether
`/*A*/` is a *declaration* per Standard (as certainly `struct a;` in the same
place would be).

It is, and we can make sure of this by several steps down through the
*declaration*-grammar:-

- Per § 7 **Declarations**, para 1, a *declaration* may be a *simple-declaration*,
  and a *simple-declaration* may be a *decl-specifier-seq*.
- Per § 7.1 **Specifiers**, para 1, a *decl-specifier-seq* may be a *decl-specifier*,
  and *decl-specifier* may be a *type-specifier*.
- Per § 7.1.6 **Type Specifiers**, para 1, a *type-specifier* may be an
  *elaborated-type-specifier*.
- Per § 7.1.6.3 **Elaborated type specifiers**, para 0, an *elaborated-type-specifier*
  may be:

  `class-key attribute-specifier-seq[opt] nested-name-specifier[opt] identifier`

where *class-key* is `class`, `struct` or `union` (per § 9 **Classes**, para 1)
and the optional *attribute-specifier-seq* does not matter because we do not
need it.

`/*A*/` satisfies:

```
class-key nested-name-specifier identifier
```

So it is a declaration.

Per Standard, `/*A*/` is a redeclaration of `a::b`.

**Some comments on GCC and CLANG**

Clang 3.3 diagnoses the posted code:

```
error: forward declaration of struct cannot have a nested name specifier
```

This is wrong because the declaration is not forward. If we move the offending 
declaration so that it *does* precede the definition of `a::b` then clang does not
fault an ill-formed forward declaration but instead diagnoses:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'
```

And if we replace `struct a ::b;` in the program with `struct a ::b x;` then
clang finds no fault with the line, therefore having found a definition of
`a::b` at the same point where previously it held that type to be (illegally)
forward-declared.

GCC 4.8.1 diagnoses:

```
warning: declaration ‘struct a::b’ does not declare anything
undefined reference to `b'
```

The warning, being just a warning, is consistent with the declaration
being a well-formed redeclaration but might more helpfully append the
word "new". If we move the offending declaration so that it
actually is forward then GCC, naturally, gives the same error as clang.

The second linkage error refers to the undefined `extern struct b`
that is called through in `main`, and which was correctly *not* supplied
with a definition by `struct a ::b;`.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is incorrect.  The tokens and whitespace are not in dispute.  A declaration can have no declarator in some circumstances, when the specifier is an elaborated type name (as it is).  A name already declared can be redeclared.

Comment: @user1131467. I believed I was answering somebody else, but their comment has been deleted!

Comment: There are two possible parses here. This answer does not explain how they are disambiguated, it merely shows how one of them works.

Comment: I am claiming there is only one possible parse of `a::b`, because by
the grammar of qualified-id at 5.1.1/8, the `::` operator must be the terminal token of a nested-name-specifier if it possibly can be. You don't agree, or something else?